# Find IDFA value during click event programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, tracking, targeting

I want to track the people who enter into my app during click event. How can I find the IDFA value when user hit the url which leads to my app programmatically?

Comment: Note that Apple is now advising against accessing IDFA in apps that don't have ads: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/issues/109

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple ways to do this. You can match user's fingerprint (p0f, or ip+ua) with IDFA, that you get after install.

Comment: Hi Виктор Перов. I already implemented using fingerprint. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can find using the following code.

NSString *idfaString = [[[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager] advertisingIdentifier] UUIDString];

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to get IDFA from browser. So I used [fingerprinting](http://motherboard.vice.com/blog/device-fingerprinting-can-track-you-without-cookies-your-knowledge-or-consent) logic to match most recent `click` with `install`